# How to convert from one date format to another in Java?

Tags: java, rft

My input is in the format of `Sep 22, 2008` and how to convert it into `9/22/2008` using JAVA?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_date_time.htm, using google does not hurt you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do like this

```
   Date date = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM d, yyyy").parse("Sep 22, 2008");
   String formattedDate = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy").format(date);
   System.out.println(formattedDate);
```

**output**

```
09/22/2008
```